# angular karma runner hangs indefinitely

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

**Windows 8 64bit**

**Node.js 0.10.5 64bit**

**Karma 0.8.5**

I am able to start karma server, Chrome browser opens (I have it defined as default browser in karma config). The issue comes when I am doing 'karma run'. Chrome changes the tab status to Chrome 26.0 (Windows) is executing. But that is all, no output on the console, no nothing. it can stay like that for hours.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have the follwoing gists: karma.conf.js and main.js (used for loading the test scripts).
I am starting the server with LOG_DEBUG and I can see that all script files are loaded.
Gist url: https://gist.github.com/mihaihuluta/5490991

Comment: Can you show your config file? Also please put verbose logging

Comment: Does it work if instead of using karma run, you set singleRun = true?

Comment: Same issue as before. Now I have singleRun =  true,Chrome browser is opened with tab status Chrome 26.0 (Windows) is executing, but that is all. It just hangs in there doing nothing I assume.

Comment: Same thing applies to Phantomjs browser.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem... it seems to be the only one upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

I personally found that if you have require.js...

`frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],`

...when you don't need it, things will just lock up at "executing..." in all browsers.

Also make sure you've specifed your adapters, eg.

```
files: [
    //adapter
    JASMINE, 
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    //...other files...
    'test/client/*.js'
]
```

Finally, I use

`logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG`

and

`browsers: ['Chrome'] //only one`

...to ensure I have the simplest test case and am getting all debug information for any failures.

Answer (score 0):

> What have described in the previous post (about not being able to run
>   karma) was just a hack. Today I decided to pay more attention to
>   details (as I should have done in the first place) and ques what...I
>   managed to have it up and running using a much more elegant and
>   official way. First I have uninstalled node.js 0.10.5 64bit and
>   installed node.js 0.10.5 x86. When I have installed karma first time I
>   used the following command **npm install karma** where the correct
>   command would be **npm install -g karma** in order to have it
>   installed globally. Once installed I added the appropriate environment
>   variables (CHROME_BIN and PHANOMJS_BIN) with the correct paths and
>   voila! All is running just fine.

That's from the blog that went down :).