# Inconsistent results from karma e2e test runner. How can I debug?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

I have a simple angular / requirejs / node project that loads correctly when viewed from a browser.  I'm trying to get e2e tests with karma set up.

I've copied all of the e2e configurations and directory structures from [the angular-require-js seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed) into my own project.  Unfortunately, the tests in my own project give bizarre (and ever-changing!) results.  Here's the stripped-down test I'm trying to run:

```js
describe('My Application', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/');
        sleep(0.5);
    });

    it('shows an "Ask a Question" button on the index page', function() {

        expect(element('a').text()).toBe('Ask a Question');

    });
});
```

## Sometimes the test fails

`Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.785 secs / 0.614 secs)`

```
Firefox 22.0 (Mac) My Application shows an "Ask a Question" button on the index page FAILED
element 'a' text
http://localhost:9876/base/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js?1375035800000:25397:     Selector a did not match any elements.
```

(but there ARE `a` elements on the page!)

## Sometimes the test hangs

`Executed 0 of 0`!  In these cases the test-runner browser does show that it's trying to run a test, but it never completes:

[image: It just stays like this forever]

It just stays like this forever.  My app *IS* displayed in the browser during this hang.

## Without `element('a')` it always passes

The only way to get consistent results is to avoid `element()`.  If I expect(true).toBe(true) then 1 out of 1 tests always pass.

## How can I debug this?

I'm at a loss for how to move forward.  The test browser is correctly *displaying* my app, with the relevant 'a' element and everything.  The test runner itself seems to only sometimes recognize that it should be running something and NEVER finds the `a` element.  Is there a way to step through the test running process?  Is this a common problem that happens when [x] is misconfigured?

Thanks for any suggestions!

## `karma-e2e.conf.js`

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  'test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js',
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['Firefox'];

singleRun = true;

proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:3000/'
};

urlRoot = "__karma__";

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304145/angular-karma-runner-hangs-indefinitely

Comment: I had not seen that question, thanks!  Unfortunately I think my problem is different.  The testing browser launches every time and I get no complaints about missing executables.  I've also had karma installed globally the whole time.

Comment: Maybe use Chrome or phantomjs instead

Answer (score 0):

How many anchor tabs do you have on the page?

You may not be referencing the actual anchor you'd expect. Add an id tag to the anchor and test again. If it is the only anchor tag in the page try to match the text rather than expect it to be. IE:

```
expect((element('#anchor-tag-id').text()).toMatch(/Ask a question/);
```

If you use chrome open the develop tools on your a element to check the actual values, this may help a lot.

EDIT:

should be

```
expect(element('#anchor-tag-id').text()).toMatch(/Ask a question/);
```

sorry added extra ( in the first example

Comment: Thanks for writing.  Unfortunately, NO anchor elements are selected in the best case, and in the worst case the tests just don't run.  Do you think your change would affect either of those issues?

Comment: I have found that tests do not run because of a typo in the code. do you only see the top banner when adding the test for expected?